# Turn off required field validation based on query string value?

Tags: validation, drupal, drupal-7, query-string

I have a registration form with about 30 fields (yes.. I know.. insanity). I need some of these fields to be required by certain types of people. What I'd like to do is just use a query string like example.com/user/register/?type=notrequired. If type = notrequired then I'd like to make to make the fields not required. Is this possible? I tried using the jQuery Validate plugin but its not working.. I'm thinking the built in Drupal validation is conflicting with it :(

Answer (score 1):

The `required` flag is set server side so I doubt you'll be able to affect it using javascript. You'll have to hook into the form and make the changes in PHP, something like this in a custom module:

```
function mymodule_form_user_register_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if (isset($_GET['element_name']) && $_GET['element_name'] == 'notrequired') {
    $form['element_name']['#required'] = FALSE;
  }
}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Hmmm this doesn't seem to be working for me. This is the first time I've made a custom module. I'm guessing all I need is the .info file and the .module file with that code in it. I have the module activated and the correct element names (assuming those are the machine readble names I inputed when making the fields).